# CSS animation not working in conjunction with another CSS+JS animation in the same code

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, squarespace

I have text that says 'View my work' and when the user overs over it, it changes from black to purple. However, the timing of it is EXTREMELY slow no matter what timing I set for transition: background-position #ms ease. I adapted this code from here: https://codepen.io/kathykato/pen/gObBybX

Here's my website where I'm using it: https://mango-harmonica-5r95.squarespace.com/aboutme

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css"></head>
<body>
  <center><h4 class="animated bounceInDown"><a href="#selected-works">View my work</a></h4>
  <span class="animated bounce"></span></center>
</body>

<style>
h4 {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  
   h4 a {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
  color: #7500FF;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000 50%, #7500FF 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  transition: background-position 5ms ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}

span.animated {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #7500FF;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

header span::before,
header span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}

span::before {
  left: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(-45deg);
  transform:         rotate(-45deg);
}

span::after {
  right: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  transform:         rotate(45deg);
}
</style>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Scroll function courtesy of Scott Dowding; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Check if element is scrolled into view
  function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return elemBottom <= docViewBottom && elemTop >= docViewTop;
  }
  // If element is scrolled into view, fade it in
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".scroll-animations .animated").each(function() {
      if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
        $(this).addClass("fadeInLeft");
      }
    });
  });

  // Click Animations
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    /*
    If any input is empty make it's border red and shake it. After the animation is complete, remove the shake and animated classes so that the animation can repeat.
    */

    // Check name input
    if ($("#name").val() === "") {
      $("#name")
        .addClass("form-error animated shake")
        .one(
          "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend",
          function() {
            $(this).removeClass("animated shake");
          }
        );
    } else {
      $("#name").removeClass("form-error");
    }

    // Check email input
    if ($("#email").val() === "") {
      $("#email")
        .addClass("form-error animated shake")
        .one(
          "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend",
          function() {
            $(this).removeClass("animated shake");
          }
        );
    } else {
      $("#email").removeClass("form-error");
    }

    // Check message textarea
    if ($("#message").val() === "") {
      $("#message")
        .addClass("form-error animated shake")
        .one(
          "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend",
          function() {
            $(this).removeClass("animated shake");
          }
        );
    } else {
      $("#message").removeClass("form-error");
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

I don't know much about java so I don't know if that is what's messing up my code. Or the other animation on my site (when you hover over 'Human Factors Engineer' the squiggly line squiggles). Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

your a tag has an animation. and transition doesn't work on animation because animation has own duration

change this 15s to whatever you want

```
a{
    animation: move 15s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: move 15s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: But don't I use the transition if I want the color to change on hover? With the original code that's what it does, but it's just extremely slow. With your code, the color changes on infinite loop but the speed hasn't changed. Any idea what I'm messing up here?

Comment: contact me in discord, Programmer#5603 or telegram @Designer1995

Comment: So it actually works fine today with the original code. Maybe it was a Squarespace issue? Appreciate your help though!